# Creating a query that shows work committed at beginning of sprint in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops

I want to create a query that shows all of the stories in a sprint on the day the sprint begins. I noticed that the built-in Velocity widget has a 'planned' bar, but I'm not entirely sure how that's calculated.

Note that some of the stories were created before the first day of the sprint, so CreateDate won't work.

Thanks!

Comment: What's the meaning of "the stories in a sprint on the day the sprint begins"? Could you elaborate? Do you mean you changed the state of the work item on the day the sprint begins? If this is the case, does `StateChangedDate` work for you?

Comment: I discovery that on Velocity Dashboard, the bar in clickable, and shows all planned US. lol

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/team-velocity?view=azure-devops

> Planned - calculated based on the amount of work assigned to the
> sprint prior to the start of the sprint. This count includes work that
> was moved to a different sprint after the start of the sprint, but
> doesn't include work that was added later after the sprint started.

If you changed the status of the work item on the day the sprint begins, you may try `State Change Date` to see whether it works for you.